# read an arrayList and store this in a File Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I want to read an arrayList and store this strings into a file. 
This is some code I have :

```
output = new Formatter(nameFile + ".txt");

 while (textLines.hasNext()){
        output.format(nameFile, textLines);
    }
```

Comment: What's the *problem* ?

Comment: And what is or isn't working as expected?

Comment: Is there a question or you're just showing us your work.

Comment: I have an ArrayList and in this arraylist are strings in. But I want to put those strings in an File. And my Code doesn't work so maybe you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class test1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String filepath = "test.txt";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");

        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            sb.append(it.next());
            sb.append(",");
        }

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath));
        bw.write(sb.toString());
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("file-name.txt");
 for(String s:yourList)    //iterate your ArrayList here
 {
    writer.println(s);
 }
 writer.close();
```

Comment: @user3649644 do select the answer if it worked for you